# I want to make the users navigate to a point on a page when they click on a link and link are dynamically coming from database

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

controller is

```
$scroll=true;
return view('frontgoso.index',compact('scroll'))->with('about',$about)->with('title',$title)- 
>with('menu',$menu);
```

view is code here :

```
@foreach($menu as $row)
   <li><a href="">{{$row->menu}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: <li><a href="">{{$row->menu}}</a></li> how i pass id of content below in this

Comment: Can you explain more? what you expect..details

Comment: Have you save any link in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem, this is solved with basic HTML (Anchor) and adding the target (point on page) to your `$menu`-item.

```
@foreach($menu as $row)
    <a href="#{{ $row->targetId }}">{{ $row->menu }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Then add an element with the same id as `$row->targetId`:

```
<div id="ID-OF-TARGET-DIV">
    My text...
</div>
```

You can also use `Str::slug()` to create unique IDs from `$row->menu`, assuming all rows are unique.

```
@foreach($menu as $row)
    <a href="#{{ Str::slug($row->menu, '-') }}">{{ $row->menu }}</a>
@endforeach
```

You still have to add each id to an html element, how to do that depends on your full code.

[See documentation for slug()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-str-slug)

Comment: more then one links are coming with this single line of code {{ $row->menu }} .how i can do in it.

Comment: @ArsalanMustafa I update my answer, can't give you a complete solution base on the code you have shared.